# How to trigger an function of an UICollectionViewCell inside an UICollectionViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to trigger the animation3() function (which is a function inside PageCell() which is a UICollectionViewCell) inside the BreathingSwpipingController which is a UICollectionViewController.

```
class BreathingSwipingController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var pageCell: PageCell?
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

    setupStartStopButton()

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    pageCell = (collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as? PageCell)!
    return pageCell!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

@objc func startStopTapped() {

```
        pageCell!.animation3()
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

Make `PageCell` a delegate  of `BreathingSwipingController` by making a protocol

```
protocol BreathingSwipingDelegate: class {
 func doSth()
}
```

now inside `UICollectionViewController` define a `weak var delegate: BreathingSwipingDelegate?`

then head to `PageCell` file and conform to that protocol

```
class PageCell:  BreathingSwipingDelegate .... {

func doSth() {
animation3()

}
var mController = BreathingSwipingController()
override init(style: .....) { 
mController.delegate = self
.
.
.
.
}
}
```

now in `BreathingSwipingController` make the following

```
@objc func startStopTapped() {

        delegate?.doSth()
}
```